# How to execute callback on page pop in Ionic 3?

Tags: ionic-framework, navigation, ionic3

I am trying to get some data from a page after it is dismissed. Since [NavController.pop](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/#pop) does not allow to specify any parameters, I am trying to use a callback.

Calling page code:

```
export class HomePage {

    constructor(
        private navCtrl: NavController,
        private articleService: ArticleService) {
    }

// this is called on second page's dismiss
onArticleFiltersDismissed(data: ArticleListFilterModel) {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (!data) {
            console.log("No data from page ArticleFilterPage");
            return;
        }

        console.log("Dismissed page ArticleFilterPage with data ", data);
        console.log("This: ", this);

        // "this" does not points to a reference of this page 
        this.filterData = data;
        this.loadArticleBriefData(data);

        resolve();
    });
}        

// this shows the second Page and provides the callback as a parameter
onShowFilter(event: MouseEvent) {
    const filterPage = this.navCtrl.push(ArticleFilterPage, { filters: this.filterData, callback: this.onArticleFiltersDismissed });

}

private loadArticleBriefData(filters: ArticleListFilterModel) {
     // load data here
}
```

The second page (that is pushed over HomePage) code is the following:

```
export class ArticleFilterPage {

    dismiss(filter: ArticleListFilterModel) {

        this.callback(filter).then(() => {
            this.navCtrl.pop();
        });
    }

}
```

When `ArticleFilterPage.dismiss` function is called, it gets the correct input, but this points to a `ArticleFilterPage` reference instead of `HomePage`, so I receive the following error message:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError:
>   _this.loadArticleBriefData is not a function TypeError: _this.loadArticleBriefData is not a function

**Question: How can I properly transfer second page's data to the first page?**

*Note: I know that using a modal is more straightforward, but the second page already opens a modal and modal over modal does not seem to work properly (second modal's dismiss will also close the first one).*

Comment: What do you mean by _modal over modal does not seem to work properly (second modal's dismiss will also close the first one)._?

Comment: @sebaferras - opening a modal page from a modal page. It actually works corectly as I have mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My question still stands, although it is an instance of [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), since my original problem was related to the second modal dismissal also dismissing the first one.

#### Possible answer for the question

Using [events](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/) is a possible solution. Second page publishes an event like:

```
this.events.publish('on-article-filter-selected', this.filterData);
```

and the first page subscribes to this event:

```
constructor(public events: Events) {
  events.subscribe('on-article-filter-selected', (filterData) => {

    this.reloadStuff(filterData);
  });
}
```

However, I am not fond about this solution since it relies on events "flying" around at application level:

> Events is a publish-subscribe style event system for sending and
>   responding to **application-level events across your app**

#### My original problem

The button opening the second modal (third page) was part of a `Form`. By default, a [button behaves as a submit](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6017), so I the mistake as not specifying the type (`button`).

Clicking the button closed the first modal and opened the second one in the same time, that's why I got the impression that second modal's dismissal closed both modals.

The most convenient solution is to have two modals, since they naturally allow to send information back and forth.

Comment: @EbruGüngör - I thought of waiting for community feedback first. Thanks.